# Product contingency matrix

Tags: r, matrix, product, contingency

I am trying to create a contingency matrix of products from a sales file.
Let's say my orders file looks like this:

```
Orders      Products
order_no_1  prod_sku_1
order_no_1  prod_sku_2
order_no_1  prod_sku_3
order_no_2  prod_sku_4
order_no_3  prod_sku_2
order_no_3  prod_sku_4
```

I need my contigency matrix to look like this:

```
            prod_sku_1   prod_sku_2   prod_sku_3   prod_sku_4
prod_sku_1      1            1            1            0     
prod_sku_2      1            2            1            1
prod_sku_3      1            1            1            0
prod_sku_4      0            1            0            2
```

What do the numbers mean? It's the number of times a product has been sold in an order along with other products.
According to the first line of the contingency matrix, `prod_sku_1` was sold in one order, `prod_sku_1` was sold alongside with `prod_sku_2` in one order, `prod_sku_3` was sold alongside with `prod_sku_1` in one order, `prod_sku_1` was never sold in an order where `prod_sku_4` was sold. 
As you can see, the top right half of the triangle table is mirroring the bottom left triangle table.

What I did was to use the `table` function with two parameters: order_no and product_sku, giving me a contingency matrix like the following:

```
             prod_sku_1    prod_sku_2    prod_sku_3   prod_sku_4
order_no_1       1             1             1            0
order_no_2       0             0             0            1
order_no_3       0             1             0            1
```

As you can see, I need the rows to represent products, just like the columns. And the matrix values to match the number of time each product was sold at the same time with all the other products.

I could loop through each order but that wouldn't be very efficient and I can't seem to find a solution to this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: you can also check out arules https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/vignettes/arules.pdf for your type of data

Comment: Apparently, I fail at searching. You are gold! Thank you very very much!